# How do you get Microsoft SQL Management Studio 2014 default columns to not nullable on creation or design?

Tags: database-design, ssms, default, create-table, non-nullable

I am new to Visual Studio Management Studio 2014.

In my database the vast majority of my data is an Id, a bit, a nvarchar(x) or the odd necessary timestamp.  Most of the columns are NULLABLE, except for end dates.

I am not saying there are not uses for NULLABLE because there are, I do have some optional binary images and enddates.  It is just that 99%+ of my columns should be NOT NULL.

However, for all these NOT NULL columns I create I have to uncheck the NULLABLE flag. Is there a way of changing this default value in the management Studio to NOT NULL?

I am also curious as to why Microsoft chose Nullable as the default it seems slightly odd to me.

It could have saved me about 500 clicks so far and I expect a lot more.

With Thanks

Robin

Answer (score 0):

On my install of SQL 2014 SSMS the default for 'Allow Nulls' is false. There doesn't appear to be an option to change it. Perhaps you can post an image to http://imgur.com/ ?

When you say 'Visual Studio Management Studio' are you talking about SSMS or VS?

Edit:

Thanks for that. This is what I get when I open the 'Create Table' window:
[image: SSMS Create Table window prior to adding anything]

'Allow Nulls' defaults to off. I've trawled through all the menu items and customisation options and there's nothing I can see that controls that. And yes, this is not the Express version, so that may be the difference.

Sorry...

Comment: Apologies I meant SSMS. I have update a screen shot to:

http://imgur.com/YIkgdDY

I just typed in Id and the rest "Type" and "Allow Nulls" are their default values.  As you can see "Allows Nulls is checked.  This is an Express edition, which may ber the difference.